# Location Not Update in ANdroid

Tags: java, android

I want to get Mobile Current Location ,When I install Application ,than first time get correct lat long but than after every time display first time get location.please give me correct code for get every time correct lat long.
_ In Sort My Location is Not Update,or Location cach not clear.
->my code

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

```
private LocationManager mLocationManager;
private Location currentLocation;

public MyLocationListener(Context context) {
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    currentLocation = mLocationManager
            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

}

public Location getBestLocationAvailable() {
    return currentLocation;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location newBestLocation) {
    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    currentLocation = newBestLocation;
}

@Override
public void nProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
}
@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
}
```

}

```
MyLocationListener loc = new MyLocationListener(MainActivity.this);
```

Location location = loc.getBestLocationAvailable();
system.out.println(location.getLatitude()+"  "+location.getLongitude);

give me write answer,why i get ever time old lat Long?

Comment: maybe location not updated.. are you sure that method onLcoationChanged was called?

Answer (score 0):

Try to get latitude and longitude inside the onLocationChnage()

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            //sets and displays the lat/long when a location is provided
            String lat = loc.getLatitude();
            String longt= loc.getLongitude();   
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Lat"+ lat+ "Long"+longt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Add the permission in menifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: I want to get lat Long without Internet,using Gps.also i update location in OnLocationChange,than no need to get lat long in OnLocationChange() method. please tell me your update.

Answer (score 0):

You code looks right, but why did you add this string?

```
mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);
```

So, you will receive only one location update and after it your listener will be disabled. Try to remove this string and check again.

Also, please note that different devices take different time for GPS "cold" start. Before testing your app, check GPS status in another app (for example maps, or GPS monitor). If your device on "cold" state, you will not receive any updates long time (10-20 minutes or more).